# Trying to connect to SQL DB via Xamarin always gives "encoding 1252 data could not be found"

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, sqlclient

I'm trying to connect to a DB via SqlClient with Xamarin and C#. The code works fine on command line but when I try to execute it on Xamarin Live Player it gives back an error that says "Encoding 1252 data could not be found".

I've tried checking the "west" box in iOS options just as I found online but it did not solve my issue. I've also tried installing the app via apk instead of running it via xam live player but it crashes on boot.

This is my code:

```
void DatabaseConnection()
    {
        string str = "";
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataReader dataReader;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = db_ip; Initial Catalog = list_name; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = my_user; pwd = my_pass;"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand("my_command", connection);

            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();


            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                str += dataReader.GetValue(1) + " - ";
            }
            Output.Text = str;
        }
    }
```

It should return "171 - " but as I said above it just crashes. I can't get my head to solve this, can anyone help me?

Comment: test using an emulator or device - Live Player is not a full fledged emulator

Comment: You mention setting the iOS i18n settings, but you also mention you're installing via APK, which suggests Android. Did you also set the `west` setting for android i18n?

Comment: @JonathonChase there's no option to set the west setting for android since the encoding issue is iOS only.

Comment: @Jason I said before i tried to install the app on an actual device but it just crashes when i run it

Answer (score 0):

this is an issue on Android also.  Android Build --> Linker in the Android project options.